# How to handle form submission using Angular material linear stepper and reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

What is the best way to add a submit button to my angular materials stepper form and only enable the submit button if all validation passes in the form progression? Any suggestion on a better solution is welcome.

I would like to:

1. add a submit button
2. disable the submit button until the form is completely validated
3. submit all the form values with the click of the submit button.

Here is my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-entry-log-form',
  templateUrl: './entry-log-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entry-log-form.component.css']
})
export class EntryLogFormComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = true; // set to false to progress through form without input
  weightMetric: string = "lbs";
  calorieMet: string = "yes";
  proteinMet: string = "yes";

  dateFormGroup: FormGroup;
  weightFormGroup: FormGroup;
  metricFormGroup: FormGroup;
  calorieFormGroup: FormGroup;
  proteinFormGroup: FormGroup;
  notesFormGroup: FormGroup;


  date = new FormControl(new Date());

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dateFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      dateCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    // need to add kg/lbs selection
    this.weightFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      weightCtrl: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2),
        Validators.min(1),
        Validators.max(700)
      ]]
    });
    this.metricFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      metricCtrl: [this.weightMetric, [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    })
    this.calorieFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      calorieCtrl: [this.calorieMet, [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    })
    this.proteinFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      proteinCtrl: [this.proteinMet, [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    })
    this.proteinFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      proteinCtrl: [this.proteinMet, [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    })
    this.notesFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      notesCtrl: [null, [
        Validators.required
      ]]
    })
    this.dateFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
    this.weightFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
    this.metricFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
    this.calorieFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
    this.proteinFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
    this.notesFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
  }
}
```

And here is the template:

```
<!-- date form -->
<mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="dateFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="dateFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Log entry date</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="dateCtrl" [matDatepicker]="picker" required>
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- daily weight form -->
    <mat-step [stepControl]="weightFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="weightFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter your weight kg/lbs</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Weight</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="weightCtrl" placeholder="Enter your weight in kg/lbs" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- metric form -->
    <mat-step [stepControl]="metricFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="metricFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Choose kg/lbs</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="metricCtrl" hidden>
                <mat-radio-group formControlName="metricCtrl">
                    <mat-radio-button value="kg">kg</mat-radio-button>
                    <mat-radio-button value="lbs">lbs</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- calories target form -->
    <mat-step [stepControl]="calorieFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="calorieFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Were calories met</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="calorieCtrl" hidden>
                <mat-radio-group formControlName="calorieCtrl">
                    <mat-radio-button value="yes">yes</mat-radio-button>
                    <mat-radio-button value="no">no</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- protein target form -->
    <mat-step [stepControl]="proteinFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="proteinFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Did you hit protein target</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="proteinCtrl" hidden>
                <mat-radio-group formControlName="proteinCtrl">
                    <mat-radio-button value="yes">yes</mat-radio-button>
                    <mat-radio-button value="no">no</mat-radio-button>
                </mat-radio-group>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- notes form -->
    <mat-step [stepControl]="notesFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="notesFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Let's hear about your day!</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
                <textarea matInput formControlName="notesCtrl" placeholder="Ex. My day was..."></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
        <p>You are now done.</p>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```